# Woocommerce - Variation Products

Tags: woocommerce

I have variation product that is, T-shirts in different sizes and different colors. I have setup all the variation data correctly. I am able to show the dropdowns and selection options on product page, but how is it possible to show a specific variation on product page. Like for example if i want to show an add to cart button for a green T-shirt which is size 4, along with all the other data.
Please suggest how is it possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by setting a default variation.

[screenshot http://cld.wthms.co/waeq+](http://cld.wthms.co/waeq+)

Answer (score 0):

The system of Woocommerce variation product create typically is so easy, just multiply each attributes.
Suppose you have two Attributes and Each Attributes has two data. That Time the Woocommerce system would generate 4 possible variation for you.
For Instance:
Attributes 1 is  Size and Size has 2 data that are large and small.
Attributes 2 is  Color and Color has 2 data that are Red and Blue.
Woocommerce will generate four possible variations that is
Large and red
Large and blue
Small and red
Small and blue
Rules: By making this variation Woocommerce follow the rules 2*2=4
If we have 3 Attributes and each attributes has 4 data then it will be
Attributes 1 is  Size and Size has 4 data that are large, small, medium and extra large
Attributes 2 is  Color and Color has 4 data that are Red, Blue, Green and Black.
Attributes 3 is  Cotton and cotton has 4 data that are Good, Bad, Medium and Very Bad.
What will be the possible variation of products?
Answer is very easy just multiply each data set. That means 4*4*4 = 64

Another Example Scenario:
If
Attributes 1 is  Size and Size has 3 data that are large, small, medium.
Attributes 2 is  Color and Color has 4 data that are Red, Blue, Green and Black.
Attributes 3 is  Cotton and cotton has 2 data that are Good, Bad.
What will be the possible variation?
ANSWER WILL BE
3*4*2 = 24
So I hope, everyone would get their answer about Woocommerce variation create Internal procedure.